# UVA - 439 - Knight Moves. What should be the reason of getting runtime error.?

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve uva problem number **'439 - Knight Moves'** using `C++ 5.3.0 - GNU C++ Compiler with options: -lm -lcrypt -O2 -pipe -DONLINE_JUDGE`

But i am constantly getting **runtime error** and i have literally no idea what causing this error. **Please note I am new in c++.**
Here is my code. I have tried bfs search to solve this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

string s1,s2;

struct pos{
    int x,y,move;
};

bool isValid(pos point){
    if(point.x <= 0 || point.y <= 0 || point.x > 8 || point.y > 8)
        return false;
    return true;
}
pos createPosition(int x,int y,int move){
    pos newpos;
    newpos.x = x;
    newpos.y = y;
    newpos.move = move;

    return newpos;
}

void BFS(pos src,pos dst){
    queue<pos> pendingQueue;
    pendingQueue.push(src);
    bool visited[9][9];
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
       for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
          visited[i][j] = false;

    while(!pendingQueue.empty()){
        pos currentPosition = pendingQueue.front();
        pendingQueue.pop();
        visited[currentPosition.x][currentPosition.y] = true;
        if(currentPosition.x == dst.x && currentPosition.y == dst.y){
            cout << "To get from " << s1 << " to " << s2 << " takes " << currentPosition.move <<" knight moves.\n";

            break;
        }
        pos new_positions[8];
        new_positions[0] = createPosition(currentPosition.x - 1, currentPosition.y - 2 ,currentPosition.move + 1);
        new_positions[1] = createPosition(currentPosition.x - 2, currentPosition.y - 1 ,currentPosition.move + 1);
        new_positions[2] = createPosition(currentPosition.x - 2, currentPosition.y + 1 ,currentPosition.move + 1);
        new_positions[3] = createPosition(currentPosition.x - 1, currentPosition.y + 2 ,currentPosition.move + 1);
        new_positions[4] = createPosition(currentPosition.x + 1, currentPosition.y + 2 ,currentPosition.move + 1);
        new_positions[5] = createPosition(currentPosition.x + 2, currentPosition.y + 1 ,currentPosition.move + 1);
        new_positions[6] = createPosition(currentPosition.x + 2, currentPosition.y - 1 ,currentPosition.move + 1);
        new_positions[7] = createPosition(currentPosition.x + 1, currentPosition.y - 2 ,currentPosition.move + 1);


        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            if(isValid(new_positions[i]) && !visited[new_positions[i].x][new_positions[i].y]){
                pendingQueue.push(new_positions[i]);
                visited[new_positions[i].x][new_positions[i].y] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    while(cin >> s1 >> s2){
        int r1,c1,r2,c2;
        r1 = s1[0] - 'a' + 1;
        c1 = s1[1] - '0';
        r2 = s2[0] - 'a' + 1;
        c2 = s2[1] - '0';
        pos src = createPosition(r1,c1,0);
        pos dst = createPosition(r2,c2,0);

        BFS(src,dst);
    }

}
```

I don't know how to solve this runtime error, and i have nowhere ask this question. Hoping that someone will help me here.

The link of the question is
[Here](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=0&problem=380&mosmsg=Submission%20received%20with%20ID%2023821437)

Comment: Fyi, you're breaching the limits of your array and invoking UB. Your indexing runs 1..8, while `visited` is only indexible from 0..7. C is a zero-base index language.

Comment: You are my hero @WhozCraig. You have saved my day. Many thanks.
On another note, why my compiler is not showing this error ??

Comment: @SodrulAminShaon C++ places a lot of trust in you, the programmer. It assumes you know *all* the rules and will never break them and it does *not* force the compiler to tell you when you break the rules - it basically specifies that the compiler can assume you'll never do so and if you do anyway it can do whatever it wants. *Don't* expect your compiler to catch your errors for you. And *don't* assume that just because "it compiles" that it is then error free..

Comment: Ponder this:  should you access a location, then check if the location is valid, or check if the location is valid then access it?

Answer (score 1):

`if(!visited[new_positions[i].x][new_positions[i].y == dst.y){` - that's not going to fly *since you never initialized `visited`*.

You never initialized members of `visited`, so they have indeterminate values and reading them is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).
Sure, you set a few of the elements (sometimes) to `true`, but what of the others? They are not magically `false`.

If you want the members of `visited` to start out as `false` (which it seems), then you *must* initialize them to that value.

Comment: I did not notice that as it is running fine in my pc. Though i have initialized that array, still not working.

Comment: @SodrulAminShaon "It seems to work" is one possible result of UB, but *not* one you can rely on.

Comment: @SodrulAminShaon You are also checking `isValid` too late, only after you used the invalid position to index into `visited`, which may be out-of-bounds. It should be `isValid(...) && ...`, not `... && isValid(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You edited the question after [Jasper Juhl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5910058/jesper-juhl)'s [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57648751/4944425), initializing `visited`, but that nested loop is not necessary:

```
bool visited[8][8] = {}; // Or since C++11:  bool visited[8][8]{};
```

You also addressed the inconsinstencies in the indices noted by [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) expanding `visited` from 8x8 to 9x9. A better approach would be to modify `isValid` and the initial transformations keeping the 0-based indeces. In the following snippet I've encapsulated those checks in the `pos` class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <stdexcept>

struct pos
{
    int x, y, move{};
    pos(int xx, int yy, int m)
        : x{xx}, y{yy}, move{m}
    {}
    pos(std::string const& str)
    {
        if ( str.size() != 2 )
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid input size");
        x = str[0] - 'a';   // from  'a', 'b', ..., 'h'  to  0, 1, ..., 7
        y = str[1] - '1';   // from  '1', '2', ..., '8'  to  0, 1, ..., 7
        if ( is_not_valid() )
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid input coordinates");
    }
    bool is_not_valid()
    {
        return  x < 0  ||  x > 7  ||  y < 0  ||  y > 7;
    }
};

int BFS(pos src, pos dst)
{
    constexpr int x_moves[] = {-1, -2, -2, -1,  1,  2,  2,  1},
                  y_moves[] = {-2, -1,  1,  2,  2,  1, -1, -2};
    bool visited[8][8]{};

    if(src.x == dst.x && src.y == dst.y)
        return 0;

    std::queue<pos> pendingQueue;
    pendingQueue.push(src);   
    visited[src.y][src.x] = true;

    while(!pendingQueue.empty())
    {
        pos current_position = pendingQueue.front();
        pendingQueue.pop();

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            pos new_position {current_position.x + x_moves[i], 
                              current_position.y + y_moves[i],
                              current_position.move + 1};

            if ( new_position.is_not_valid()  ||  visited[new_position.y][new_position.x] )
                continue;

            if( new_position.x == dst.x  && new_position.y == dst.y)
                return new_position.move;

            pendingQueue.push(new_position);
            visited[new_position.y][new_position.x] = true;
        }
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Sorry, I can't find a solution");
}

int main()
{
    std::string source, dest;
    while(std::cin >> source >> dest)
    {
        try
        {
            std::cout << "To get from " << source << " to " << dest
                      << " takes " << BFS(source, dest) << " knight moves.\n";
        }
        catch(std::exception const& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << ".\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GGvylfKvxz0rPJcN).